# Keycloak 21.1 ldaps integration "SHA1 used with certificate"

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ldap, keycloak, cacerts

I have a problem to connect to a ldaps connection. I already added the certificate to the server:

[image]

I also used the openssl command to verify the url and certificate and I got a successfully response:

openssl s_client -connect ip:port -CAfile /path/to/certificate.pem

response:
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
Extended master secret: yes

[image]

The "Test connection" to the ldap works well (I also did a telnet test to the ip and port) but the "Test authentication" gives me the following error:

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on disabled algorithm: SHA1 used with certificate:
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
... 83 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on disabled algorithm: SHA1 used with certificate:
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:224)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:144)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:83)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:364)
... 88 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on disabled algorithm: SHA1 used with certificate:
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$DisabledConstraint.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:997)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:531)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:262)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permitsPSSParams(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:231)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:217)
at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:208)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:285)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)

I'm not finding any solution. Has anyone had the same problem or have any idea what it could be?

Many thanks!

Comment: The solution is to not sign the server certificate with a SHA1-based signature algorithm

Comment: See https://openjdk.org/jeps/288 for details